# compare value equality of objects

Tags: vb.net, oop, object, equality

I would like to know the best way to compare 2 complex objects to know if they are equal by value, ie, their properties are the same?  I tried the serialize method and not sure why they are not equal by value

```
    Dim stream As New MemoryStream()
    Dim bstream As New MemoryStream()

    Dim clientOne As Jewellery.ClientInfo = New Jewellery.ClientInfo(New Jewellery.Company("a", "", "", "b", "", "e"), New Jewellery.Customer("a", "b", "c", "d", "", "", "", "f"))
    Dim clientTwo As Jewellery.ClientInfo = New Jewellery.ClientInfo(New Jewellery.Company("a", "", "", "b", "", "e"), New Jewellery.Customer("a", "b", "c", "d", "", "", "", "f"))

    formatter.Serialize(stream, clientOne)
    formatter.Serialize(bstream, clientTwo)

    Dim streamOneBytes As Byte() = stream.ToArray()
    Dim streamTwoBytes As Byte() = bstream.ToArray()
    Dim streamToCompareBytes As Byte() = streamToCompare.ToArray()
    Dim i As Int16 = 0
    Dim flag As Boolean

    If streamOneBytes.Length <> streamTwoBytes.Length Then

        MsgBox("False")
        flag = False
    Else
        While i < streamOneBytes.Count

            If streamOneBytes(i) <> streamTwoBytes(i) Then
                flag = "False"                   
            Else : flag = "True"                    
            End If

            i = i + 1

        End While

    End If
```

As you see in the above code, when I initialize 2 objects of the same type and compare, it works correctly.  But when I add one object to say a List and then retrieve and compare to an object of similar type, it fails saying the binary width are different for both.  Any advice?  Thanks

Comment: You may want to look into overriding the [`Equals` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: If clientInfo.Equals(CType(Me.FindResource("clientInfo"), Jewellery.ClientInfo).ClientRegistrationList.Item(1)) Then
            MsgBox("True")
        Else : MsgBox("False")
        End If

Comment: Tried the above code but it does not work with Equals.

Comment: Did you actually override the `Equals` method in your `ClientInfo` class to make it perform an equality check based on whatever your rules for equality should be?

Comment: No I didnt.  I wanted to skip that because I will need to compare say 10 properties.  Thought serializing both objects and comparing each byte will be enough?  It is working as in the above code but for some reason, when I put it in a List and retrieve later to compare, the byte width differs! Why? So according to you, I will need to override Equals and make each comparison simultaneously? like this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
public class IntegerPropertyEqualityCompare : IEqualityComparer<Main>
{
    #region IEqualityComparer<Main> Members

    public bool Equals( Main x, Main y )
    {
        return x.IntegerProperty == y.IntegerProperty;
    }

    public int GetHashCode( Main obj )
    {
        return obj.IntegerProperty.GetHashCode() ^ obj.StringProperty.GetHashCode();
    }

    #endregion
}

public class StringPropertyEqualityCompare : IEqualityComparer<Main>
{
    #region IEqualityComparer<Main> Members

    public bool Equals( Main x, Main y )
    {
        return x.StringProperty == y.StringProperty;
    }

    public int GetHashCode( Main obj )
    {
        return obj.IntegerProperty.GetHashCode() ^ obj.StringProperty.GetHashCode();
    }

    #endregion
}

public class AllPropertiesEqualityCompare : IEqualityComparer<Main>
{
    #region IEqualityComparer<Main> Members

    public bool Equals( Main x, Main y )
    {
        return ( x.IntegerProperty == y.IntegerProperty ) && ( x.StringProperty == y.StringProperty );
    }

    public int GetHashCode( Main obj )
    {
        return obj.IntegerProperty.GetHashCode() ^ obj.StringProperty.GetHashCode();
    }

    #endregion
}



public abstract class Main
{
    public int IntegerProperty { get; set; }
    public string StringProperty { get; set; }

    public bool Equals( IEqualityComparer<Main> comparer, Main other )
    {
        return comparer.Equals( this, other );
    }
}

public class ConcreteA : Main
{ }

public class ConcreteB : Main
{ }




class TemporaryTest
{
    public static void Run()
    {
        var a = new ConcreteA();

        a.IntegerProperty = 1;
        a.StringProperty = "some";

        var b = new ConcreteB();
        b.IntegerProperty = 1;
        a.StringProperty = "other";

        Console.WriteLine( a.Equals( new IntegerPropertyEqualityCompare(), b ) );
        Console.WriteLine( a.Equals( new StringPropertyEqualityCompare(), b ) );
        Console.WriteLine( a.Equals( new AllPropertiesEqualityCompare(), b ) );
    }
}
```

Maybe then somthing like this?

Comment: Hi shadow.  Thanks for the code although I have not tried it yet, was working on some other piece of code.  Seems complicated enough though for me because wouldnt it be easier for me just to overwrite Equals as  James suggested for the fields I need to compare according to my business rules?  Reason I wanted to implement comparing bytes was to reduce amount of work and complicated code.

Comment: For sure you can just override the Equals method. It is the simplest and in some cases the most efficient way in terms of complexity/simplicity of project or/and time you have on your hands. The example I wrote gives you more freedom and flexibility. It's not hard to follow. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understand what you want to do.
So I go with `IComparable<T>`.

Comment: I want to compare 2 ClientInfo objects as in the above code to see if they contain the same information in the fields like NAME, SURNAME, etc without having to actually do an Equals manually for each field in the objects am comparing.  In the above code, I initialized 2 ClientInfo objects as you see with Customer's Firstname = "a", Surname = "b" for demonstration.  So basically, these 2 objects are equal in value for me.  If one of the fields differs, then it is not equal.  So, if I override Equals, I will need to compare each Firstname, surname, ...., etc for each object which i want to skip